# Quickly navigate to an ASP.NET MVC view's controller?

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-2017

In an ASP.NET Core Web Application, using Visual Studio 2017.

When I have some view open in the editor, say Foo.cshtml, is there a way to get a list of the controllers which return that view?

(Kinda like how I can jump to the view from the controller by pressing F12 on `return View()`;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While inside a view or Controller:

- <kbd>Ctrl+M</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl + G</kbd> will return the controller's location, you can either go back or forth between view and controller using this HotKey.

However it always returns single controller you can't find out how many actions are using this view using this hotkey.

There is also Another Approach to this. you can search within entire solution or application with the name of the view. either its used like `return view("X")` or the `ActionResult X()` and with a `return view()` inside it. all of those will point to the `X` view.